# Help with my application please! Can't open image(s) with error: External component has thrown an exception

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, .net, windows

I have an application written in C# I believe and it adds images to a SQL Server 2005 Database. It requires .NET 3.5 to be installed on my computer. I installed .NET 3.5 and setup a database. It runs fine but then once it gets to image 100 when running on one computer, It stops and gives me this error: Can't open image(s) with error: External component has thrown an exception....

When I run the program on my own computer I am able to reach 300 images but then it stops after 300 images and gives me Can't open image(s) with error: External component has thrown an exception.... error once again.

please help!

Answer (score 1):

Check the application log on the machine to see if there's a stack trace to go with the exception. 
I think you're most likely to need help though from whoever coded the application or you could possibly try stackoverflow.com